# replace specific color and it's shades in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make web tool that will allow people to replace colors in simple 2 color images that I am selling. Images that I am using are saved in jpg format. I did look here and there and I did come up with following code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
 canvas.width = img.width;
 canvas.height = img.height;
 context.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 

 var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 var pixelArray = imageData.data;
 var length = pixelArray.length / 4; 

 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var index = 4 * i;

    var r = pixelArray[index];
    var g = pixelArray[++index];
    var b = pixelArray[++index];
    var a = pixelArray[++index];

    if (r === 0 && g === 0 && b === 0 & a === 255) {
        pixelArray[--index] = 47; 
        pixelArray[--index] = 255; 
        pixelArray[--index] = 173; 
    }
 }

 context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

img.src = "assets/images/tijana-mala.jpg";
```

Unfortunately I came into realization that many of the pixels are not just "black or white" but there are different shades of it. Complexitiy of images is rather simple, I sell quotes: Text on the background, using variety of fonts.

Is there a way to do this beyond my piece of code?

Thank you

P.S. My competition made it there: 
http://www.crownprintsart.com/color
username: your email address
password: crownprintsdemo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Transfer Luma To Alpha Channel

In the method I would recommend we can first convert the black data to an alpha channel based on the "luminance" of the the color. This will keep the anti-aliasing which is the cause for the various shades along the edges as well as allowing us to use composition modes.

Although not stated, if the black is not pure black (ie. is actually dark grey) we can compress the range by using a simple threshold value in combination.

Then color the white background using `source-atop` composition mode, and finally draw in the new color for black (which is now the alpha channel) using `destination-atop` composition mode.

Using composition modes is better for performance as you don't have to bother mixing the color manually.

### Using Threshold Value

A different method is to use a threshold value. If the color (grey/luminance) is above a certain value turn it into color A, if below into color B etc.

However, the problem with this is that anti-aliased edges will loose its purpose and become a solid part of the edge which is not desirable as the edge will end up jaggy as if not anti-aliased. We can reduce the problem by using a very high-resolution original which we later scale down but the penalty is that there is more data to iterate.

## Manual Color Mixing

We can also mix the colors manually. Use a value from one of the channels as a normalized luminance/grey value and mix the two color based on this value (pseudo):

```
luma = redColor / 255;  // or green/blue assuming image is grey-scale
newColor = Math.round(colorA * luma + colorB * (1 - luma));
```

## Example Using Composition Modes

This example uses the first technique. Grey below is the browser background color to show the alpha channel -

[image: stage 1] [image: stage 2]

**Final result**

[image: result]

```js
var img = new Image,
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");

img.onload = setup;
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ZJHabAD.jpg";

function setup() {
  // draw in image (scaled for demo)
  c.width = this.naturalWidth;
  c.height = this.naturalHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  
  // create alpha channel from "black" pixels
  var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height),
      data = idata.data;

  for(var i = 0, v; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    v = data[i];
    if (v < 30) v = 0;  // compress grey to black (arbitrary threshold here)
    data[i+3] = v;
  }
  
  ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
  
  // replace white color
  ctx.fillStyle = "#AF4979";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
 
  // replace "black" (alpha)
  ctx.fillStyle = "#C6AF47";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}
```

```css
body {background:#777}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: I still have no idea how you did this and what it means BUT IT WORKS. Thank you so much dear friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the exact value you can check if the color is near a specific value. There may be a better way to do it but here's my solution:

```
var precision = 10;

var replaceColor = {
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 0,
    a: 255,
};

var isInRange = (
    r >= replaceColor.r - precision &&
    r <= replaceColor.r + precision &&
    g >= replaceColor.g - precision &&
    g <= replaceColor.g + precision &&
    b >= replaceColor.b - precision &&
    b <= replaceColor.b + precision &&
    a >= replaceColor.a - precision &&
    a <= replaceColor.a + precision
);

if(isInRange) {

}
```

Hope this helps